# How to restore Windows 8 from recovery USB to new drive?

Tags: windows-8.1, hardware-failure

Ok, so my mom's Lenovo G780 running Windows 8.1 seems to have a bad drive. She got a popup along the lines of a corrupted disk and to immediately back everything up. She had dropbox so everything is backed up, and I created a **USB recovery disk**. I did `chkdsk /offlinescanandfix` and it found a couple bad sectors. After fixing them the original popup came back. Again I did the `chkdsk` command again and it fixed it...

SO we decided to buy a new drive ($54 for 1TB seemed like a prudent investment). So I opened up the laptop and replaced the drive, then put it all back together, plugged in the USB and booted it.

It boots into the USB just fine and I get a blue screen and asks to choose the keyboard layout. I select US and I get a new menu titled "Choose an option"

1. Troubleshoot (Refresh or reset your PC, or use advanced tools)
2. Turn off your PC

Selecting `Troubleshoot`, I have two options:

1. Refresh your PC
2. Reset your PC
3. Advanced options

Selecting `Refresh your PC` then gives me the message `The drive where windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again`. I'm not sure if it is locked, but there is no windows install on the drive as I just took the drive out of the package. I only have a Cancel button.

Selecting `Reset your PC` then gives `Unable to reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing.` Um, no it's on the USB...

I have variations on the theme with the Advanced Options menu.

So, how does one actually use the USB recovery disk to reinstall Windows?

Comment: “So, how does one actually use the USB recovery disk to reinstall Windows?” - **You dont** the recovery drive can only be used to repair a Windows installation.  You need to download the current Windows 8.1 ISO and install Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the recovery "disk" withought having a hard drive to recover. You need to go download a new windows iso, write it to a cd/flash drive and reinstall your os from scratch. I'd recommend just using windows 10 because windows 8 is loosing support in a year or two *(i think)*. You can always install windows 10 withought a product code and activate it later however you want. I'd recommend doing it legally, but to each their own.

link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't make a Windows Recovery Drive, you made a Windows Recovery Environment drive.  All you have is the WinRE based fix, not the actual image of Windows.  I suggest downloading the Windows installer disk from Microsoft and using that to reinstall Windows.